# Jquery AJAX request to ASMX page error preflight 500

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net, web-services, asmx

I am trying to figure out why I am getting the following error when trying to POST to my web service:

[image]

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://zzzzzzzz/sqlWS/Service1.asmx/theQ.
>   Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500

The asmx code is this:

```
<WebMethod(CacheDuration:=60)> _
<ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=False, ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString:=False)> _
Public Sub theQ(ByVal qString As List(Of String))
    Dim results As Object = fetchSQLQ("query", qString(0))

    Try
        Dim ser As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim strResponse As String = ser.Serialize(results)

        Context.Response.Clear()
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"
        Context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", strResponse.Length.ToString())
        Context.Response.Flush()
        Context.Response.Write(strResponse)
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Context.Response.Clear()
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"
        Context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", ex.Message.Length.ToString())
        Context.Response.Flush()
        Context.Response.Write(String.Format("[ERROR: {0}]", ex.Message))
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
    End Try
End Sub
```

The AJAX code:

```
var sqlQ = "SELECT TOP 50 LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(OID, ' ', ''))) FROM vPS_DAT WHERE OID != ''";

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(xhr){ xhr.withCredentials = true; },
    headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
    url: 'http://zzzzzzzzzzz/sqlWS/Service1.asmx/theQ',
    data: JSON.stringify({ qString: [sqlQ] }),
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(obj);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(err.Message);
    }
});
```

My web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE"/>
        <add name="Allow" value="OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, Content-Type, Accept"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <namespaces>
        <clear/>
        <add namespace="System"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Specialized"/>
        <add namespace="System.Configuration"/>
        <add namespace="System.Text"/>
        <add namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions"/>
        <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
        <add namespace="System.Xml.Linq"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Caching"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.SessionState"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Security"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Profile"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Not sure honestly even where to begin to debug it...

This web service does work if i call it from within the domain the web service is being hosted at.

```
 ex: Calling http://zzzzzzzzzzz/sqlWS/Service1.asmx/theQ from  http://zzzzzzzzzzz/sqlWS/index.html **WORKS**

 ex: Calling http://zzzzzzzzzzz/sqlWS/Service1.asmx/theQ from http://yyyyyyy/somepage.html **DOES NOT WORK**
```